# find and change properties with the value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a nested javascript object called data. Is there any way to iterate through it and find all properties that have the value undefined and set it to a string, "undefined" insted. JSON doesnt validate if the property value is undefined in IE7. Thanks

```
{
"Target": "System",
"Systemoperation": "Buy-In",
"Systemorigin": "ABB",
"Subscriptionmode": "Maintain & Evolve",
"Evolveto": "800xA",
"Quoteselection": "Full Quote",
"Commitmenttimeframe": "3 years",
"codevalues": {
    "Target": 100,
    "Systemoperation": 110,
    "Systemorigin": false,
    "Subscriptionmode": 4,
    "Evolveto": undefined,
    "Quoteselection": "fullquote",
    "Commitmenttimeframe": 3
},
"Route": [
    "System",
    "Buy-In",
    "ABB",
    "Maintain & Evolve",
    "800xA",
    "Full Quote",
    "3 years"
],
"currentsystem": ""
```

}

Here is evolteto in codevalues undefined. Which does not validate (try http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Please create an example for us to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Johan My code works in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your data structure (nested objs):

```
data = {
  a: undefined,
  b:{
    c: '1',
    d: undefined
  }
}
```

Then, this works for you

```
for (var items in data) {

  if (data[items] === undefined) {
    data[items] = 'undefined';
    continue;
  }
  for (var i in data[items]) {
    if (data[items][i] === undefined) {
      data[items][i] = 'undefined';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there no beter way than checking each level?

Answer (score 0):

A very crude search but works,

```
for(var prop in arr)
{
    if(typeof arr[prop] === 'object')
    {
        for(var subprop in arr[prop])
        {
            if(typeof arr[prop][subprop] === 'undefined')
                arr[prop][subprop] = "undefined";
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h27dp/1/ - JSON validator also validates the result obtained here as a "Good JSON"

Answer (score 0):

```
function disp(j) {
  for(var key in j) {
    if(j.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(typeof j[key] === "object") {
        disp(j[key]);
      }
      else {
        if ( j[key] === undefined) {
          j[key] = "undefined";
        } // if undefined key
      } // else
    } // if hasOwnProperty
  } // for  
} // function
```

And then call it with

`disp[data];`

Comment: when i log the data object all i get returned is undefined

Comment: check now. earlier closing bracket was missing at line 3. check a fiddle at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aR1ndAm/Y23zf/1/)

Comment: yep, but if i type `console.log(disp(data))` all i get is `undefined` shouldnt i see the "new" data object?

Comment: oh ok. if u type console.log(disp(data)) you are trying to find the info about the function. If that is the case u should type console.log(disp). But if you want to see the data object, you would have to type console.log(data). Also for that to work, data must be defined in some scope that can be accessed from the console. Especially to be clear, I had added the type in the document.write section so that you can believe it is actually string. I was hoping you would use the JSON somewhere. that should solve your problem. As for looking it, I really can't tell what is the best way.

Comment: Be rest assured that the type of undefined is now string after this JS. Use it wherever you want, that should solve the purpose